# Formulário continua aberto após this.close()

Tags: c#

Eu tenho um formulário de menu principal, que chama o de cadastro de alunos.

Porém o código de saída do formulário de alunos não o fecha, chama o formulário principal mas ele continua aberto de fundo e não posso nem fechá-lo manualmente.

Código para abrir o menu de cadastro:

```
frmCadAluno oloko = new frmCadAluno();
this.Visible = false; 
oloko.ShowDialog();
```

Código para fechar:

```
FrmMenuPrincipal oloko = new FrmMenuPrincipal();
oloko.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
this.Dispose();
```

Comment: "codigo para abrir", qual o form origem? é o menu principal? No "codigo para fechar", tente fechar o form atual antes de abrir o menu principal

Comment: Pergunta mal feita. Melhore isso aí.

Comment: @AugustoVasques 

Comment: Você está abrindo o oloko e fechando o this, que seria o form que abriu o oloko, tenta oloko.Close()

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu peço desculpas, primeira vez utilizando o stackoverflow. O meu erro era no showdialog, devia ser apenas show().

Comment: @BrunoMoraes [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 4):

O erro era usar `showdialog()` ao invés de `show()`.

Comment: +1 por ter respondido uma pergunta ininteligível. Mesmo que seja sua.